# C# Can you save object that called a method to another object as reference node

Tags: c#, class, variable-assignment

Having problems stating the question title, but I think that sums it up.

What I want to do is this:

Object 1 has a method that adds a sub-object to an array; Object 2 is passed through the parameter of the method; then, I want Object 2 to assign Object 1 to it's Parent reference node automatically on being added.

Here an an example:

```
    Room1 = new Area(10, 10, "Anthony's House");
    R1_LivingRoom = new SubArea(5, 5, "Living ROom");
    int[] loc = new int[2] {10,10 };
    Room1.setSubArea(loc, R1_LivingRoom);
    R1_LivingRoom.Parent = Room1;
```

I would like a way of keeping track of hierarchy without needing to assign it myself like in this example. It would be nice if:

> ```
>     Room1.setSubArea(loc, R1_LivingRoom);
> ```

Automatically preformed:

```
      R1_LivingRoom.Parent = Room1;
```

On being added to Room1.

Am I doing it the only possible way? To assign it outright or pass the Room1 through a parameter of sorts? Or is there a way to make it where when it's added through setSubArea, it can reference the calling object which is Room1 and automatically assign it to parent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class Room
{
   public void setSubArea(int[] loc, SubArea room)
   {
       //some code
       room.Parent = this;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's what I initially did and it doesn't work for me. When I call the room.Parent, it doesn't return it. But when I assign it directly outside, it does (room.Parent = Room1). Does "this" not really return a reference to the calling object?

Comment: It must work, possibly you are disposing the object somewhere or do something else, I can't say what without insight into your code. Try some very simple test case that does just this and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Yea, it worked. I was doing some bounds checking and forgot to change it to within bounds. Thanks, I need to learn to double check more.